# Fitness health/apps: Export personal data from phone (i.e Dafit)

Tags: applications, internal-storage, export, fitness, smartwatch

Many apps used by smartbands/watches have no option to export your personal data, so you can't process/visualize, store, or migrate to other app.

Also I know that some fitness apps for android apps allow the data export to external files as excel, such as Withings healthmate can sync data with its "cloud/server" and from their webpage you can export data to excel.

For *Dafit and other fitness apps* with export/import :

Do you know **apps/options/methods to extract its data**?

Do you know  **apps to process/convert data from different apps** ?
/convert this

Answer (score 0):

Though i haven't found specific apps I found method for "powerusers".

Dafit stores its information in plain text inside a SQlite database files, there are several tables with apparently no relationship (maybe from code there are few relations).

How to extract/process the data:

1. Extract data file from Android

- Option1. Find the data folder (from android), copy&paste to accessible folder ¿root req?
- Option2. Do a backup (titanium backup, oandbackup,...) and unzip the content of backup to a folder

2. Open file with a SQLlite tool
3. Export to spreadsheet/excel tables and process/transform there
4. Process/transform using SQL queries.

Comment: I got the file, but it does not seem to be a database file at all. The first 16 bytes are
00 00 00 18 00 00 00 00 followed by eight FF.